# How to undo accidental setting of permissions of /etc to 400

Tags: linux, sudo

I accidentally set the permissions of /etc/ to 400 with `sudo chmod 400 /etc/`.  Now I can no longer undo that because when I sudo it says `unknown UID 1000 - who are you?`, presumably because sudo can no longer access the directory.  Is there a way to undo this?

Comment: What Linux distribution is it?

Comment: Depending on your your setup, you might be able to boot into rescue mode or something.  0400 should still be readable, so if you boot in a way that drops you directly to a root shell you should may be able to fix some things.  If you can do this, and how to do it depends on your system.

Comment: The linux is Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Zoredache - thanks - tried a few things but couldn't get into root mode.  Ended up restoring from backup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can no longer access `/etc/passwd` and similar so the system can't work out who you are.

You will likely need to attach the disk to a different system or boot from rescue media to fix it, or rebuild and restore from backup.

Comment: yep, ended up restoring from backup.